# Using sed to remove line breaks after execute command and save it on array

Tags: arrays, bash, sed

I'm working on some inventory stuff and i'm trying to save all the AWS regions on one array, then, showed elements one under another to use it as an input menu.

This next command is giving me the right output but when i walk into the array with FOR, the array length is just 1 cause the result is:

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --output text|awk -F\t '{print $3}'| sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g'
```

> eu-north-1 ap-south-1 eu-west-3 eu-west-2 eu-west-1 ap-northeast-2
>   ap-northeast-1 sa-east-1 ca-central-1 ap-southeast-1 ap-southeast-2
>   eu-central-1 us-east-1 us-east-2 us-west-1 us-west-2

This is how i'm filing the arrays:

```
# Get regions
declare -a regions=$(aws ec2 describe-regions --output text | awk -F\t '{print $3}' |  sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /')
echo -e "\nPlease, select the region you would like to query: "

# Print Regions
len=${#regions[@]}
last=$((len+1))
for (( i=0; i<$len; i++ )); do
    echo -e "$i.${regions[$i]}\n" ;
    done
echo -e "$last All of them (this could take a while...O_o)\n"
read region_opt

if [${region_opt}!=${last}] then
    region=(${regions[$region_opt]})
```

What i want to have in the output is something like

> 1. eu-north-1
> 2. ap-south-1
> 3. eu-west-3 ....

Comment: When you write `-F\t` you're telling awk to split the input on the letter `t`, exactly as if you just wrote `-Ft` since `t` isn't a metachar. Did you mean to write `-F'\t'` to split the input at tab characters? Whatever that arcane sed script is doing you could do clearly and legibly in awk - post a separate question if you'd like help with that.

Comment: `declare -a regions=( $(aws ec2 ...) )` would fill regions as an *array* -- without `( $(...) )` you are filling only the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing parentheses around your array values, e.g.,

```
declare -a ARRAY=(value1 value2 ... valueN)
```

(refs: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html, https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)

The following forms also work, and the first (without `declare -a`) is given as an example in the [GNU's Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html), the [Bash guide for beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/), and the [Advanced bash-scripting guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/):

```
ARRAY=(value1 value2 ... valueN)
```

```
declare ARRAY=(value1 value2 ... valueN)
```

Comment: `declare -a` is fine. The real issue was the missing `( ..)`.

Comment: That's true! y add another pair of (...) and worked. Thanks!

Comment: @NahuelPerez, please accept the answer then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$()` is command substitution, is just convert any stdout to string and assign it to a variable
if you said true that the result is;
`eu-north-1 ap-south-1 eu-west-3...`
then to get array out of it, make it syntactically appear so, then tell Bash to evaluate it as such,

```
regions=($regions)
```

after expansion it'd be the valid array syntax

```
 regions=(eu-north-1 ap-south-1 eu-west-3)
```

then would be evaluated as valid array after it's enclosed by `""` and as Bash `eval` argument

```
$ eval "regions=($regions)"
$ echo ${regions[0]}
eu-north-1
```

So that I am sure you will be able to accomplish and solve it on your own...